# Please clarify the behavior of addObserver and deleteObserver in the Observable class?

Tags: java, android, observable, ondestroy

Some context:

I'm creating an observer in an Activity class and adding it to an Observable class in the onCreate method of the Activity.  The Observable is essentially being held by the Application class.  I will delete it from the observable in onDestroy.  However, it looks like there's some possibility that onDestroy will not be called, or that not all code in onDestroy is guaranteed to be executed.  Since there is a reference to the object in an external class (in the observable), I'm worried that the object will persist.

If the observer outlives the activity, and the Activity is recreated, another Observer with the same type will be created and added to the Observable.  In this case, will the existing Observer of the same type be deleted ?

I can find this out with trial and error, but I haven't really found an answer to this question elsewhere.

tl;dr:

If I create two separate Observer classes of the same type, and add both of them to a single Observable class in Java, will java replace the first observer when the second one is added?

Referring to this documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html

It's not clear to me if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing observer will not be removed. You can see this in the source code of Observable. The objects created are different, despite having the same type. They are both added to the vector of observers.

Comment: Good point, should have checked the code.  Thanks for the reply!